# Create timer on a scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, timer, scrollview

How would I go about creating a timer function on a scroll view.

I have implemented a timer function that works correctly however due to the nature of a scrollView the view controller loads everytime the page is swiped & the timer gets reset.

How would I store the value of the timer from each page of the scrollView, so that it doesn't reset?

Below are my timer functions:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // Start Timer Variables
    startGame()
    timerButtonStart()

}
```

**Timer Functions**

```
// Mark : Timer Functions

func startGame() {

    let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

}

@IBAction func pauseTimer(sender: AnyObject) {

    if timerPaused == false {

        elapsedTime += startTimeDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
        timer.invalidate()
        timerPaused = true

    } else {
        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTimeDate = NSDate()
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() + elapsedTime
        timerPaused = false
    }
}

func updateTime() {

    var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    //Find the difference between current time and start time.
    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

    //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)

    //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.
    let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

    //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants
    let strMinutes = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes):"0" + String(minutes)
    let strSeconds = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds):"0" + String(seconds)
    strMinutesGlobal = strMinutes
    strSecondsGlobal = strSeconds

    //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel
    timerLabel.text = "\(strMinutesGlobal!):\(strSecondsGlobal!)"
}


func timerButtonStart() {
    var refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, target: self, action: "timer") //Use a selector
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshButton

    navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    title = "Search result"
}
```

Comment: Does the view controller that your scrollview is nested in change?

Comment: It doesnt change - It refreshes every time someone swipes left or right though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent that your NSTimer gets deallocated when switching view controllers, you could store the NSTimer instance in a separate singleton class instead of the view controller.

```swift
class MyTimer {
    var sharedInstance = MyTimer()

    var timer: NSTimer?
}
```

With this, you can access the NSTimer instance like this:

```
MyTimer.sharedInstance.timer
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I understand the logic behind it, but I am struggling to implement it. Do I put all my functions inside the new class & just call the timer function from my main ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your timer creation code to

```
if (timer == nil) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

and also when you invalidate your timer you will need to set it to nil. This will only recreate the timer if it doesn't already exist.